# No route to host, after database update

Tags: php, mysql, magento, amazon-web-services, bitnami

i have a magento store running by bitnami on the AWS

i recieved an email from amazon telling me that i have to upgrade their database, so i followed the instructions here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.OSUpgrades.html
then i got this error on the site http://smartkoshk.com/

i tried changing /etc/local.xml many times, it didn't work
i check the socket path in the database and in php.ini, they are identical
i deleted the magento cache under /var/cache, nothing changed
i restored the AWS to a snapshot i toke before the upgrade, and it still the same

so what is the problem?

Comment: Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691148/magento-db-connection-parameters-wont-change-crazy-caching , maybe it helps

Comment: thanks, that was half of the solution

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710441/1420619
i had file called local1.xml beside local.xml
first i delete it and tried a lot of hosts ips
until i tried the value "Endpoint" of the RDS
you could find it in the details, it is something like
xxxxx.asdfoiasdlkf.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com